# Tag-lib issue with migrating Struts2 to Tomcat 8.Its working on tomcat7

Tags: java, struts2, tomcat8

Currently migrating web application to JDK 8 and Tomcat 8.
Struts 2.3.1.2 is used in the application. Face issue . 
Please find below files.

TagLib.jsp

`<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>`

Top.jsp
<%@include file="/pages/includes/taglibs.jsp"%>
<s:text name='label.LastViews' />

`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/base/twoPanelTemplate.jsp (line: 13, column: 2) /pages/includes/top.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) null
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:471)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1435)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)

Comment: Person that set this question as uncler,Tell me what he doesn't understand. 
This is very basic problem in startup. Please suggest at what point i need to start.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding below to web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
<taglib>
         <taglib-uri>/struts-tags</taglib-uri>
         <taglib-location>/struts-tags</taglib-location>
 </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: I had an issue because I had disabled Jar scanning in Tomcat, which is needed for annotations to function correctly.